# Running a Terraform process inside Rundeck

Tags: terraform, rundeck

I'm discovering Rundeck; is there a way to create and run a Terraform process from inside Rundeck?
Thanks in advance
Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can call your Terraform scripts from the [command step](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#command-step) or the [script step](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#script-step) on your workflow in the same way you can call any program. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZbYjZ73w-Y) you can see a complete example of Rundeck+Terraform integration (and about how to automate your deploys).

UPDATE: Also you can test (and collaborate) with [this](https://github.com/MegaDrive68k/rundeck-terraform-steps-plugin) unofficial plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was wondering it Rundeck has something integrated, to avoid creating local scripts.

Comment: For now, maybe it's a good opportunity to build some plugin focused on Terraform: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/01-plugin-development.html

Comment: Plugins are only developed in Java?

Comment: Java: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/04-node-execution-plugins.html#java-plugin-type, Script (bash / PowerShell) https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/tutorials/custom-script-plugin-hello-world.html#develo:ping-a-custom-rundeck-script-plugin, and Groovy: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/12-option-values-plugins.html#groovy-plugin-type :-)

Comment: Nice! I don't do java or groovy but I'll look at the bash part :D

Comment: Also (and I forgot to mention it) you can create Python-based plugins, here you can check a lot of plugins examples(java, groovy, python, and bash): https://github.com/rundeck-plugins